# Test that Delayed Job is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, delayed-job

I am trying to test that a part of my code is running a DelayedJob.
Here's code:

```
def start_restream
  ...
  puts 'Here'
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(Restream::StartAllJob.new(channel.id))
  puts 'After'
  ...
end

#app/jobs/restream/start_all_job.rb
class Restream::StartAllJob < Struct.new(:channel_id)
  def perform
    puts "Inside"
    ...
  end
end
```

In my `spec_helper.rb` I have `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false`.
The spec:

```
it 'runs Delayed::Job::Restream::StartAll' do
  post :start_restream, :id => channel.id
  expect(Restream::StartAllJob).to receive(:new)
end
```

It prints out

```
Here
Inside
After
```

when running, so I know that it is called. But test fails:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Restream::StartAllJob).to receive(:new) 

(Restream::StartAllJob (class)).new(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Or, if I use `expect_any_instance_of(Restream::StartAllJob).to receive(:perform)` it says

```
Failure/Error: example.run
       Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: perform
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the mistake I made in the order:
  `expect(Restream::StartAllJob).to receive(:new)` should be written before `post :start_restream, :id => channel.id`